# Find a number pattern in multiple lines of random numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a lot of lines like this (let's say there are 20 lines like this): `1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 13, 16, 18, 19`.
10 unique random generated numbers form 1 to 20.

I want to find a group of 4 numbers that are from the same line and found in most of the lines.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Where do you have the lines? Would you like an algorithm or C# sample code?

Comment: Do you mean any four numbers from a line, or four consecutive numbers?

Comment: That's great. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? Can you explain what kind of pattern you are looking for and post the code that isn't working for you?

Comment: @alexinblue: C# sample would be best, algorithm is good

Comment: define "found in most lines". Did you mean maximum most appearing pattern of 4 numbers?

Comment: Are you trying to find four numbers from the same line that are most prevalent amongst the entire set of numbers and lines, or are you trying to find a set of four numbers which is most prevalent? (Are we treating the numbers individually or as a monolithic set?)

Comment: @Guffa: any four numbers from the line

Comment: @nawfal: yes maximum most appearing pattern of 4 numbers

Comment: You could start by counting how many times each of the numbers `1` through `20` appears in all the lines. Then first maybe see if the four most frequent numbers come together in one single line. If so, that's your solution. If not, you can run through all the lines and remember the total occurence of the four most common numbers in that line. The "optimum" is your result, as I understand you.

Comment: @levib: four numbers from the same line that are most prevalent amongst the entire set of numbers and lines

Comment: @Sp3ct3R this is no way related to design patterns. Btw, this is a good question, but unless you show us what you have tried and where you are stuck, this will tend to be closed. At SO you dont shop code generally.

Comment: @nawfal i want an algorithm so i don't know what i can show you if i don't know how to start. And i searched on Google but i didn't find anything because i can't find a therm to describe this type of algorithm.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: that wouldn't work. Alternating lines could contain 1,2 (but not 3,4) and 3,4 (but not 1,2). That would (most likely) 1,2,3,4 make the most common pattern. If that pattern would occur on a single line, your algo would call it a solution, but most likely it isn't!

Comment: @igrimpe I see. You're probably right. But one will need a more precise definition of what the Original Poster wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question itself is interesting imho

As a starting point I would create all possible combinations of the quadruples (?) that might occur and store them as (List Of) INTEGER (because that will allow you to work with bitwise compare). The number of combinations should be (20*19*18*17)/4! => 4845.
Then you convert your input "lines" to integer too. After that, you can simply count the number of occurences of a single "pattern" by checking `NumberFromLine & NumberFromList == NumberFromList`

Storing the patterns in an integer means: If the number is "1", you set Bit 0 of the integer to 1. If the number is 7, you set Bit 6 of the integer value to 1 and so on.

I think this should qualify as an "algorithm", so you just need to code it ;)

Comment: Thank you! I think this could work. I will try to code it later.

Comment: You might want to edit your question according to the comments and questions to make your question more clear - esp for searchers who might face a similar problem!